# Deleting rows with certain keywords of csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large data file and I need to delete rows that have certain keywords.

Here is an example of the file I'm using:

```
User Name     DN
MB31212       CN=MB31212,CN=Users,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
MB23423       CN=MB23423 ,OU=Generic Mailbox,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
MB23424       CN=MB23424 ,CN=Users,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
MB23423       CN=MB23423,OU=DNA,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
MB23234       CN=MB23234 ,OU=DNA,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
```

This is how I import file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=',', encoding='latin1')
```

How can I

1. Delete all rows that contain 'OU=DNA' in DN column for example?
2. How can I delete the first attribute 'CN= x' in the DN column without deleting the rest of the data in the column?

I would like to get something like what is posted below, with the 2 rows that contained 'OU=DNA' deleted and the 'CN=x' deleted from every row:

```
User Name     DN
MB31212       CN=Users,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
MB23423       OU=Generic Mailbox,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
MB23424       CN=Users,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
```

Comment: I would suggest looking into grep to delete rows, and awk to delete columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this two-step filtering as your logic. Use the `str.contains` method to filter out rows with `OU=DNA` and use `str.replace` method with regular expression to trim the leading `CN=x`:

```
newDf = df.loc[~df.DN.str.contains("OU=DNA")]
newDf.DN = newDf.DN.str.replace("^CN=[^,]*,", "")
newDf

    UserName    DN
0   MB31212 CN=Users,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
1   MB23423 OU=Generic Mailbox,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
2   MB23424 CN=Users,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
```

A little break down of the regular expression: `^` stands for the beginning of the string which is followed by `CN=` and use `[^,]*,` to capture pattern until the first comma;

Comment: I get there error "TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'" When I use this.  IT works with sample data, but I am using a large data file. Any help with this?

Comment: It's likely that your data frame contains missing values. Remove or double check before you apply `contains` method should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, some of the User Names have no information.  If I need to keep them... then I cannot use contains?

Comment: You can add a missing value checker as this `df.loc[~(~pd.isnull(df.DN) & df.DN.str.contains("OU=DNA"))]`.

Comment: How do I take out multiple values at once? df.loc[~(~pd.isnull(df.DN) & df.DN.str.contains("OU=DNA", "CN=Users"))] present an error @Psidom

Answer (score 2):

To read the file sample you gave I used:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep='     ', encoding='latin1', engine="python")
```

and then:

```
df = df.drop(df[df.DN.str.contains("OU=DNA")].index)
df.DN = df.DN.str.replace('(CN=MB[0-9]{5}\s*,)', '')
df
```

gave the desired result:

```
    User Name   DN
0   MB31212     CN=Users,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
1   MB23423     OU=Generic Mailbox,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
2   MB23424     CN=Users,DC=prod,DC=trovp,DC=net
```

Comment: this worked using the sample file.. but I'm using large data file.. error that occurs: 'ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values'. There are some rows that are blank and have no information in them.  Any help with this?